# Selenium C# bypass Open/Save Dialogbox of Firefox

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I am working in an automatic process that has to download a excel file from a website. The problem is that when I do driver.FindElment(By.Id("Button")).Click(); there is a pop up windows that tells me if I want to save or download the file I cant handle it directly with selenium I am wondering how can I bypass this pop up with c#, Can anybody help please?

P.D I attached an image of the situation [image]

Comment: Set your firefox profile `firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream doc xls pdf txt");`

Comment: Nice I would try it how ever I already got a solution I am using c# and what I did to resolved this is to use     SendKeys.Send("{Down}");
                SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
                SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
                SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
                SendKeys.Send("{Enter}");

Comment: Doubt its going to work if you are running firefox headless. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I finally fixed what I did was to use AutoITx Like this below :                   AutoItX.WinActivate("Opening ZBI_ANALYSIS_PATTERN_V1.xls");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                SendKeys.Send("{Down}");
                SendKeys.Send("{Tab 3}");
                SendKeys.Send("{Enter}");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);